# TextMate Snippet: How to uppercase the first letter in a regexp

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

How can I make the first letter upper case in the following:

```
${1:${TM_FILENAME/[\.php]+$//}}
```

Basically if the filename is "welcome.php", I'd like it to write out "Welcome". This at the moment writes "welcome" (lower case w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following snippet. Works for me.

```
${TM_FILENAME/(.*?)(\..+)/\u$1/}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the above example gives you weird charectors when using it ... it took me a while but the solution below works if you are still looking. It has two solutions here for you the first one is for actual textmate on mac:

```
${TM_FILENAME/(^.)(.*?)(\.php)/(?1:\U$1)(?2:)(?3:)/}
```

The next is if you are using e Texteditor on PC:

```
${TM_FILENAME/(^.)(.*?)(\.php)/(?1:)(?2:$2)(?3:)/}
```

I hope this helps you if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

TM_FILENAME not works for windows?